# Custom widget for type object in rjsf

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

Im trying to create a custom widget to write a free json using a text area. But `@rjsf/core` form doesnt seem to allow it. My custom `JsonWidget` component is a text area, but the default widget is appearing.

```js
import RjsfCoreForm from "@rjsf/core";
import { JsonWidget } from "./JsonWidget";

const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    free_object: {
      type: "object",
      additionalProperties: true
    }
  }
}

const uiSchema = {
  free_object: { "ui:widget": "JsonWidget" }
}

const widgets = { JsonWidget }

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Form</h3>
      <RjsfCoreForm schema={schema} widgets={widgets} uiSchema={uiSchema} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there any way to do it? You can check the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-water-2yd8tb).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its not possible (found at [docs](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/custom-widgets-fields/#adding-your-own-custom-widgets)):

> You can provide your own custom widgets to a uiSchema for the following
> json data types:
>
> string
>
> number
>
> integer
>
> boolean
>
> array